# All queries of Internet Explorer are slowed after a proxy is applied (including those bypassed directly)

Tags: windows, proxy, internet-explorer

I have set up an internet access limited PC for the special demand of our company, setting up a non-existent proxy server address of IE and adding those bypass sites to the excluded lists; however, after this proxy is applied, accessing any sites in IE have slowed down significantly, including some local webpages.

- Although this method can meet the requirement, the user experience is badly affected:

  ```bash
  Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

  Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d "0" /f

  Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyOverride /t REG_SZ /d "*.speci-addr.com;<local>;" /f
  ```

What can I do about this?

Comment: Why on earth would anyone be asking anyone else to support internet explorer for a reason like this?  Internet Exploder is at end of life (thank the Lord).  Good luck getting help with this.

Comment: If there is any other choice, we would not choose IE....But the demand is to block the address bar,hot keys, favorites, Settings,develop tools and all buttons that the users may do anythings to the web browser or access some websites that not on our permitted list. We have tried others, but none can meet the requirements besides IE (or developed a browser ourselves)

Comment: Have you tried Chromium Edge? It has excellent website compatibility where IE was once required.

Comment: @RuiRui Simply having Internet Explorer installed creates a non-fixable exploit due to an IE-only file extension association, with IE losing update support in 2017 _(it's received some security patches, but development ceased in 2017 and, as of this year, is no longer supported by Microsoft)_. It's likely a Chromium-based browser, like [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?r=1), supports the same customizations since the base code is opensource, and if any [legacy] sites require IE, the [IE Tab](https://www.ietab.net/) extension can be used to emulate IE in a Chromium-based browser.